# Windows automatically downloads CA certificate on school network but not Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireless-networking, certificate

When I try to connect to my school's WiFi network through my personal Windows machine, a prompt opens up to enter my ID number and password, which allows me to connect to the network. When I try to connect on a linux VM though, a larger prompt appears with options for encryption/authentication methods.

I've done some research and figured out what are the properties that I should need to set to get it working, but it ends up failing to connect. I believe this is because I don't have the CA certificate file on my VM which the network seems to need. I'm confused on this though, as this wasn't an issue while connecting on Windows. Is Windows automatically trusted in an AD network like this and downloads the CA certificate? Is it possible to get linux to connect to a network like this? My school does not openly allow us to download the certificate from them.

I understand there are no specific details/logs in my post. Unfortunatly I don't have access to the network for a little bit so I can't recreate the issue while making this post. If more information is needed for possible solutions let me know and I will update this post when I can!

Comment: "Is Windows automatically trusted in an AD network like this and downloads the CA certificate?" - An AD domain server can indeed be configured to push trusted CA certificates to a machines certificate store while connected to the domain. I am going under the assumption that "AD network" means an Active Directory domain.

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows doesn't automatically *download* the CA certificate; instead it doesn't *check* the site certificate against a CA at all.

PEAP is just TLS under the hood and works exactly like in HTTPS, where the CA certificate is not something that you must to supply to the server, but the opposite – it's used by the client to validate what is being supplied *by* the server. So you *can* connect both to websites and to PEAP-secured networks without CA verification, it just won't be quite as secure as it should.

If you don't specify the correct CA certificate, Windows skips CA verification but switches to an SSH-style "trust on first use" system where it remembers the server's "leaf" certificate it saw the first time and expects it to remain the same throughout – that's the "Are you expecting to find this network here y/n" prompt you get. (I believe iOS does the same for PEAP, and Firefox does this for HTTPS.)

Unfortunately NetworkManager on Linux doesn't implement this alternative, so you must figure out what CA certificate is being used, e.g. from wpa_supplicant system logs. (You do have the option of disabling certificate checks in NetworkManager, but that leaves you with no server verification at all – meaning anyone can set up a Wi-Fi access point with the same SSID and grab your password – so only do that as a last resort.)

> My school does not openly allow us to download the certificate from them.

That's a bit silly of them. But more likely they just didn't think it would be needed to be publicly available – perhaps they're expecting you to use a setup tool (such as Eduroam CAT, which runs on Linux) to automatically install it.

Note that many institutions have started using public web CAs for PEAP recently. In that case, there is no need to specify an individual CA (and no point in doing so, either) – instead you are supposed to select the "Use system CAs" option and specify the *server domain* that should be matched against the certificate (not AD domain, but more like the equivalent of the website URL).

Of course, there are still schools that use internal CAs as well. If your network uses AD Certificate Services, there is usually a way to download the CAs from the AD domain controller (AD CS publishes everything to LDAP by default), or to export them to file from any domain-joined Windows PC.

Comment: Thanks for all of this great info! Could you be a bit more specific on possible solutions? I can't find any info on disabling certificate checks on network manager and I can't find my wpa_supplicant log (I'm on kali).